# Alteração de Senha IdentityUser - AspNet

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Eu tenho um formulário de registrar, que registra o usuário com email, e a senha, porém surgiu a necessidade de alterar essa senha, e utilizando a `class` `Identity`, ela possui o campo `PasswordHash`, e eu queria poder alterar a senha cadastrada. É possível alterar ?

Essa é a forma que eu altero os outros dados:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(EditViewModel model)
    {
        var teste = model.Usuarios.Email;
        var userInDb = db.Users.Where(u => u.Email.ToLower().Equals(model.Usuarios.Email.ToLower())).FirstOrDefault();
        userInDb.PasswordHash = model.Usuarios.PasswordHash;
        userInDb.FirstName = model.Usuarios.FirstName;
        userInDb.LastName = model.Usuarios.LastName;
        userInDb.PhoneNumber = model.Usuarios.PhoneNumber;


        db.Update(userInDb);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();


        //StatusMessage = "A conta do perfil foi atualizada";
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");

    }
```

Porém não sei como alterar a senha, pesquisei e não achei nada até então explicando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É só usar o método [`ChangePasswordAsync`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.changepasswordasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

No **ASP.NET Core** use dessa forma:

```
ApplicationUser appUser = db.Users.Find(userId);
var result = await UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(appUser, model.NewPassword);
```

Segue abaixo um exemplo de método de alteração de senha utilizando o Identity:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ChangePassword(ChangePasswordViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var result = await UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(userId, model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
        if (user != null)
        {
            await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { Message = ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess });
    }
    AddErrors(result);
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Ah sim, entendi, mas eu não consigo fazer no formulário que eu já uso para alterar ? É possível ?

Comment: @marianac_costa Consegue sim, esse é só um exemplo, só precisa adaptar pro seu caso.

Comment: George, eu estou tentando fazer, mas ele sempre cai no `false`, eu mudei a forma de pegar o `Id` para `ApplicationUser userId = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);`, pq qndo tento dessa forma que vc me passou ele retorna esse erro:'IIdentity' não contém uma definição para 'GetUserId' e não foi possível encontrar nenhum método de extensão 'GetUserId' acessível que aceite um primeiro argumento do tipo 'IIdentity'

Comment: @marianac_costa, agora que vi que tem a tag do core tbm, vou editar.

Comment: Dessa forma que você passou tb retornou erro, tentei assim `ApplicationUser appUser =await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            var result = await _userManager.ChangePasswordAsync(appUser, model.Change.OldPassword, model.Change.NewPassword);` dessa forma sua, não entendi muito bem. Quando eu pego o usuário eu faço assim em outras funções `ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);` tentei assim, e mesmo assim ele retorna `false`

Comment: Sua resposta me ajudou a chegar na resposta correta, eu tive que alterar é o `HashPassword` dessa forma: `var newPassword=_userManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(user,newpass);
        user.PasswordHash = newPassword;
        var res =await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);` obrigado.